# apiClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow, return a OAuthToken in localhost but null in test enviroment

Tags: docusignapi

We are testing the use of Docusign, within the approval flow of a business application. 
We are using the OAuth solution for Service integrations, the JWT (JSON Web Token) flow.

When I call the apiClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow method in the aplication hosted in IIS Localhost, I obtain the OAuthToken and can send envelopes.

But when I deploy the solution on the Test server, with the same userId, integratorKey and privateKey, the call to apiClient.ConfigureJwtAuthorizationFlow method return null.

I did:
https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/auth?response_type=code&scope=signature%20impersonation&client_id=XXXXXXXXXXXX&redirect_uri=https://www.docusign.com

Do you have any idea how to fix this? What's the matter?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the [C# .Net Core](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-csharp-jwt-core) or [C# .Net Framework](https://github.com/docusign/eg-01-csharp-jwt-framework) examples? See if one of those examples work on your Test server. If they do, the problem is in your code. If they don't then they are the first issue to be solved.

As you say, there should be no difference in where you run your application.

The usual issues to be checked for a test server: Firewall rules, DNS configuration, SSL root certificate store, etc.

Also, the url you gave is used for manually granting consent. It is only needed once per user (on demo). You only use that URL once to grant consent. After that, the JWT token can be used to get an access token which impersonates the user.